# How to extract values from a vector and create a diagonal matrix?

Tags: r, input, output, economics

I have a vector of n numbers, for simplicity assume that

```
test <- c(1:100)
```

It is simple to construct a diagonal matrix for a vector with diag().

However, I want to extract every value of the vector and create a 4x4 matrix with the extracted value being in i = 1 and j = 1 (upper left hand corner) and all other values being zero.

Personally, I have no clue whatsoever how to accomplish that.

Why do I want to do that? I'm performing Input/Output analysis and want to calculate the inoperability of a sector. For that I need the sector recovery time which is in a vector of 1000 randomly generated recovery times from a pert distribution.

To be more precise:

If I have this vector from 1:100 I want to extract every value from 1:100 and create a separate matrix that looks like this (for 1 to 100):

```
1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Difficult to know exactly what you mean here. Is `lapply(1:100, function(x) diag(4) * x)` what you are looking for?

Comment: I just tried to formulate it more precisely. So basically 100 new matrices with the value from the vector being in the upper left corner i = 1 j = 1.

Comment: In that case you probably need `lapply(1:100, function(x) matrix(c(x, rep(0, 15)), 4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly shorter version would be

```r
lapply(1:100, function(x) matrix(c(x, rep(0, 15)), 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
lapply(1:100, \(z) {
    m <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 4);
    m[1,1] <- z;
    m})
```

if possible sparse matrices, could be more memory efficient:

```r
lapply(1:100, \(z) {
    Matrix::sparseMatrix(1, 1, x = z, dims = c(4,4))
})
```

Comment: if any future reader might wonder how I go from here with this code: I've basically assigned the above to a new variable. This is now a list of 100 matrices. You can easily create new matrices with "for (index in 1:length(m)){
  assign(paste0("matrix", index), m[[index]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}" where "m" is the list

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a 3D array:

```
test <- 1:100
nr <- 3L
nc <- 4L
a <- array(0L, c(3, 4, length(test)))
a[1,1,] <- test
a[,,1]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0
a[,,12]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]   12    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0
```